# Why python glob.glob does not match any files with the wildcards I passed in?

Tags: python, glob

For example:

```
20190108JPYUSDabced.csv
20190107JPYUSDabced.csv
20190106JPYUSDabced.csv
```

When I search the first 2 files from terminal:

```
bash: ls /Users/Downloads/201901{08,07}JPYUSDabced.csv
it gives me the first 2 files (exclude 20190106JPYUSDabced.csv)
```

When I do in python:

```
import glob
glob.glob('/Users/Downloads/201901{08,07}JPYUSDabced.csv')
it gives me []
```

Comment: From what I see from the docs, I don't think python's glob library supports the `{opt1,opt2}` syntax.  At least, there's no mention of it on https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch or https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Comment: `glob.glob` is using [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.fnmatch) under the hood which does not seem to support all shell wildcards, including `{..,..}`.

Comment: Here's the issue that's been open on the subject since 2011.. https://bugs.python.org/issue9584

Answer (score 4):

According to the docs for the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) module, under-the-hood `glob` uses [`fnmatch.fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fnmatch.html). The only patterns the `fnmatch` doc describes are:

> ```
> Pattern   |    Meaning
> --------- | -----------------------------
> *         | matches everything 
> ?         | matches any single character 
> [seq]     | matches any character in seq 
> [!seq]    | matches any character not in seq
> ```
>
> For a literal match, wrap the meta-characters in brackets. For example, '[?]' matches the character '?'.

Try using sequence of characters in brackets instead:

```
glob.glob('/Users/Downloads/2019010[87]JPYUSDabced.csv')
```

#### Using os.walk

Assuming you're looking to search for specific date ranges, you might need to try using [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) with [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html) regexes to get the more complex pattern you're looking for.

*Caveat:* `os.walk` recursively goes through every dir from the starting location, which may not be what you desire.

You'd have to tailor the regex to whatever your situation is, but here's an example:

The regex matches either date `20181208` or date `20190107` but must contain the identifier `JPYUSDabced.csv`.

```
regex = re.compile("(?:(?:20181208)|(?:20190107))JPYUSDabced.csv")

files = []
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/Users/Downloads'):
    for f in filenames:
        if regex.match(f):
            files.append(os.path.join(dirpath, f))
print(files)
# ['/Users/Downloads/20190107JPYUSDabced.csv', '/Users/Downloads/20181208JPYUSDabced.csv']
```

Comment: the real condition is more complecated that [8,7] is not working.
     20181208JPYUSDabced.csv
     20190107JPYUSDabced.csv
     20190106JPYUSDabced.csv
and I want the first two files with glob.glob

Comment: @Maik is your real goal: list all files labeled with 2 specific dates?

Comment: Also be ware `glob.glob('/Users/Downloads/2019010[8,7]JPYUSDabced.csv')` also matches `'/Users/Downloads/2019010,JPYUSDabced.csv''` which I presume is not what the OP wanted. *matches any character in seq* means just that "any character" (incl. `,` which happens to also be a character in the answer).

Comment: @OndrejK. whoops; you're spot on. removed the comma. ahh i see now you'd edited that out in the first place. sorry about that

Comment: Yeah, I am still afraid it only works for the example in question, but actually OP might want `"{09,10}"` for instance or even more complex pattern and is out of luck with `[seq]` notation. I suppose combo of `os.walk() or such and regex filter will ultimately be the solution.